# Would using an underscore in a domain name have a negative effect on ranking?

Tags: seo, domains

What do you think the effect on search engine ranking will be if one uses an underscore in a domain name?

Comment: This question already exists here, more specific to [digits](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/774/are-there-any-downsides-to-starting-a-domain-name-with-a-digit) and [hyphens](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/410/is-it-better-to-put-hyphens-in-a-domain-name). You cannot use underscores in domain names.

Comment: Your original question has been edited as you included a couple of questions that has already been discussed on Pro Webmasters. @dan has listed those similar questions above.

Answer (score 2):

*Underscores in Domain Names*

While it may be perfectly valid by [RFC 2181 (section 11)](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2181.txt) to have underscores in a domain name, you will not find any domain type i.e TLD, ccTLD or gLTD  that supports registering domains with underscores in, you are therefore restricted to hyphens as an separator.

> The DNS itself places only one restriction on the particular labels that can be used to identify resource records. That one
>   restriction relates to the length of the label and the full name.
>   [...] Implementations of the DNS protocols must not place any
>   restrictions on the labels that can be used. In particular, DNS
>   servers must not refuse to serve a zone because it contains labels
>   that might not be acceptable to some DNS client programs.

You can however use underscores in the hostname, sub domain or URL but this is very subjective as its agreed that in most cases, the hyphen serves the purpose better, especially in the hostname environment.

Comment: Although it would seem to be [RFC1123](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1123.txt) (which modifies [RFC952](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc952.txt)) that defines the "syntax of a legal _Internet host name_", which states just _letters, digits and hyphens_ (with some additional restrictions on their placement).

Answer (score 0):

Host names cannot contain an underscore (RFC 1123). This seems a bit counter-intuitive since domain names can contain underscores...but remember, the domain name is a label pointing to a series of records. Several of those records contain host names (A and MX for example). The records that contain host names can't use underscores.

IF your domain registrar let you create a domain name with an underscore, you wouldn't be able to add any valid host names to it, but you could add other types of records (TXT, SRV, CNAME, etc.). Since most people want to have host names in their DNS records, domain registrars won't accept domain names that contain an underscore.

Comment: A host name and domain name are two separate things and do not occupy the same space. Host names are not valid on the Internet unless used as part of a domain name. I realize that linux installs want to use the host name as a sub-domain, however, that is completely optional and often wrong to do. The question is in regard to domain names having an underscore (_) and the effect on search performance. What does a host name have to do with the domain name having an underscore and search performance?